# Socket.io one to one chat

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, mern

As per the documentation one to one chat happens when we emit the message to the specific socket.id.
for example

```
io.to(socket.id).emit("event","message")
```

This will only work if two users are connected at the same time.
If we are to add chat feature in our application where registered users can chat with each other (1-1).What is the optimal solution for that.I have implemented the chat using io.to(socket.id),but when one of the user is offline socket.id is not available.

**-----------------------------------Client-------------------------------**

```
function Chat() {
const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(null);
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState(null);
const scrollRef = useRef();
const socket = useRef();
const client = isAuthenticated()

const clientId = isAuthenticated().client._id;
const token = isAuthenticated().client.token
console.log(clientId)



useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8900");
    socket.current.on("getMessage", (data) => {
      setArrivalMessage({
        sender: data.senderId,
        text: data.text,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      });
    });
  }, []);



  useEffect(() => {
    arrivalMessage &&
      currentChat?.members.includes(arrivalMessage.sender) &&
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
  }, [arrivalMessage, currentChat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.emit("addUser",clientId );
  
  }, [client]);



useEffect(() => {
getconversation(clientId,token).then((data)=>{
    if(data.error){
        console.log(data.error)
    }else{
        console.log(data)
        setConversations(data)
        
    }
})
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
const getMessages = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/messages/" + currentChat?._id);
    setMessages(res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
getMessages();
  }, [currentChat]);


useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messages]);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const message = {
      sender:clientId,
      text: newMessage,
      conversationId: currentChat._id,
    };

    const receiverId = currentChat.members.find(
      (member) => member !== clientId
    );

    socket.current.emit("sendMessage", {
      senderId: clientId,
      receiverId,
      text: newMessage,
    });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/messages", message);
      setMessages([...messages, res.data]);
      setNewMessage("");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

-------------------------Server-----------------------------------------

```
const io = require("socket.io")(8900, {
cors: {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
},
});

 let users = [];

 const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
 !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) &&
  users.push({ userId, socketId });
  };

  const removeUser = (socketId) => {
   users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
   };

  const getUser = (userId) => {
    return users.find((user) => user.userId === userId);
    };

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    //when connect
    console.log("a user connected."+socket.id);


    //take userId and socketId from user
    socket.on("addUser", (userId) => {
  
      addUser(userId, socket.id);
      io.emit("getUsers", users);
      });

    //send and get message
    socket.on("sendMessage", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
    console.log("receiverid=====>>>",receiverId)
    console.log("users ",users)
    const user = getUser(receiverId);
    console.log("userSocket Id",user)
    io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
    senderId,
    text,
     });
    });

//when disconnect
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  console.log("a user disconnected!");
  removeUser(socket.id);
  io.emit("getUsers", users);
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it is needed to store the messages within your app, along with the details of the sender, receiver and timestamp. Then use the web sockets / socket.io to complement the functionality and inform each user real time, if they are online.
This approach is what other chat apps follow eg Slack.

So the main properties of your app should be,

1. When user sends a message, the client should post it to the back end/server for storage.
2. The server should emit through sockets the message. This will get more sophisticated with pub-sub services etc once you get bigger and have clusters.
3. The users that are online will receive the message and will be rendered on the chat screen.
4. If users refresh or user is offline and returns, all messages for that user will be fetched from the server.

About the emitting part, use unique identifiers eg a unique identifier (uuid) of the session generated between one or more users, to target a room (the users should listen to this identifier) or the user ids and emit to each user id (the user can listen to their own user identifier once they are online). The details of the message should be enough to help the app render it on the right screen.

Comment: I have stored the messages in my DB with sender and receiver Id. Application works fine when user A and User B are connected at the same time.When one of them is not connected my socket server can't find the socket.id of the receiver and it crashes..

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli you can maintain the connected users (or room/group sessions if you prefer) upon socket connection and disconnect (on('connection') and on('disconnect')) within your own data structure in server memory, no need to persist it. Then iterate and trigger to whoever you still find connected.

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli have you tried using socket."emit"? I see no error when socket.emit('to something random',...

Comment: Let me edit the question I will share my code so you can have a look at it.

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli ok that's fine, so why don't you skip the emit if there is no "socket.id"? in other words there is no reason to push the event through web sockets if there is no client connected on the other end to receive it.

Comment: So what can I do to send the message when receiver connects. lets say  user A wants to send message to user B. But user B is not connected  at the time when user A sent the message, user B should get the message when he connects....

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli user A sends the message to the server, according to 1 in my explanation above, which I think is what the call within the client  `const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/messages", message);` is doing.
But since the other user B is not online the `io.to(user.socketId)` will be ignored.
When user B returns all messages will be fetched from the server, according to 4 from the explanation above, which I think is what the call within the client of "getMessages" `const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/messages/" + currentChat?._id);` is doing.